# How to add Days through AngularJS Date Filter?

Tags: angularjs, date

I have this code:

```
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="my-controller">
  <h1>Empty Angular App</h1>
  <span>{{"2015-07-08T15:10:10.530Z" | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
  <span>Expected: Aug 23, 2015 10:10:10 PM</span>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/vicheanak/pen/MwVNwG/

I'd like to add 46 days on top of "2015-07-08T15:10:10.530Z".
Expected result is: Aug 23, 2015 10:10:10 PM

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "add Days"? This question is not very clear

Comment: Sorry about that, just edit the description. Add 46 days to the "2015-07-08T15:10:10.530Z". Thanks

Comment: How do you know how many days you'd like to add? Will it always be 46, as in your example or is that another piece of data? Why do you feel that a filter is the best way to do this?

Comment: No I don't feel so, I feel javascript is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you told, use javascript is better option.

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

app.controller("my-controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "world";
  $scope.mydate = new Date("2015-07-08T15:10:10.530Z");

  var numberOfDaysToAdd = 46;
  $scope.newdate = $scope.mydate.setDate($scope.mydate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwVNpq

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom filter to convert the date from the format ISO8601 and add X days:

```
myApp.filter('kDateAddFromDateISO8601', [function() {
  return function(isoDateString, days) {

    var parts;
    var isoTime;
    var date;

    isoDateString = isoDateString || "";
    days = days || 0;

    parts = isoDateString.match(/\d+/g);
    isoTime = Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
    date = new Date(isoTime);

    if (days) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    }

    return date;
  };
}]);
```

And then you can use the filter:

```
<div>{{"2015-07-08T15:10:10.530Z" | kDateAddFromDateISO8601 : 46 | date:'medium'}}</div>
```

Output:

**Aug 23, 2015 12:10:10 PM**

[Check the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/rrhbp2v4/3/)

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, but for Angular 8. Thank you very much!