# AngularJS datepicker add to number of day

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have an AngularJS form that includes 'start date' and 'duration' fields, and I need to calculate an 'end date' based on what the user inputs into these two fields i.e.
end date = start date + number of days

But I'm struggling converting them into correct number format to calculate the 'end date' correctly.

Here is the basic code:
HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Start Date: <md-datepicker ng-model="date" md-placeholder="Enter date" >
  </md-datepicker></p>
<p>No of days:<input ng-model="noDays" type="number"></p>
<p>End Date: {{date+ noDays}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

And jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/benct/n6jwj61s/

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31298008/4130107) answer here

Simply write an updateDate function which adds the days:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Start Date: <md-datepicker ng-model="date" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change='updateDate()'>
  </md-datepicker></p>
<p>No of days:<input ng-model="noDays" type="number" 
                ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'
                ng-change='updateDate()'></p>
<p>End Date: {{enddate}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.date = new Date();
$scope.enddate = new Date();
$scope.noDays = 0;
$scope.updateDate = function() {
   $scope.enddate.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + $scope.noDays);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ts70opub/1/)

Comment: Great, thank Tobi for this. It works correctly the first time, but if the user then  amends the 'no. of days' input a second time, it works incorrectly. It starts adding the number of days to the 'End Date' rather than the 'Start date'. I believe this is a fix for this https://jsfiddle.net/benct/ts70opub/2/

Comment: Yes, See the updated answer, the endDate has to be an extra variable then.

Comment: You also should add the ng-change=updateDate() to the date-picker!

Comment: Done, sorry that I overlooked that Tobi