# How can I change the function AddDays from the C# in this code, using Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, datetime

I have this code in C#:

```
public static DateTime FeriadosMoveis(int ano, string  feriado)
{
    DateTime data = DeterminarPascoa(ano);

    switch (feriado)
    {
        case "Carnaval":
            return data.AddDays(-47);
        case "Quarta":
            return data.AddDays(-46);
        case "SextaSanta":
            return data.AddDays(-2);
        case "CorpusChristi":
            return data.AddDays(60);
    }

    return data;
}
```

I need to implement the same code using Angular 6, but Visual Studio Code indicates an error with the `AddDays` method. How can I implement the same function in Angular 6? :

```
export class FeriadosMoveisComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

CalcularPascoa(ano: number, feriado: string) {
    let data: Date;
    switch (feriado)
    {
        case "Carnaval":
            return data.AddDays(-47);//carnaval é sempre 47 dias antes da pascoa
        case "Quarta":
            return data.AddDays(-46);
        case "SextaSanta":
            return data.AddDays(-2);
        case "CorpusChristi":
            return data.AddDays(60);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Angular is a framework, not a language. Javascript is the language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297479/how-to-add-days-through-angular-date-filter

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, Angular is a framework, that uses TypeScript as a programming language, a superset of JavaScript. Your `data` object is a [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) object, which does not have a `AddDays` method. JavaScript dates have fewer manipulation methods that [C# DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects. I would recommend you use a library such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to provide you with the same ease of use when performing date arithmetic.